# Bash creating user and assigning existing folder as home wrong permissions

Tags: linux, bash

```
name=$1
folder=$2

useradd $name
echo "user $name added successfully!"
echo $name:"123" | chpasswd
echo "Password for user $i changed successfully"

usermod -d ~/Projects/$folder -m $name
echo "Home set for user"

sudo chown -R $name:$name ~/Projects/$folder
sudo chmod -R 755 ~/Projects/$folder
```

User gets added with password, and setting the home folder works perfectly. Problem is when SSH into the server with the newly created account and I get this error `Could not chdir to home directory /root/Projects/project12: Permission denied`. Have tried many different versions of chmod.

How can I fix the error in the best way? *Please don't mind the password, this is just for **testing purposes***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the projects directory out of the `/root` folder. By default the permissions for this directory are `0700` so only root can access it. And this should not be changed.

Comment: This helped me so much, thank you. Perfect